# Puppet clients applying empty classes (with default parameters)

Tags: couchdb, puppet, httpbackend, hiera, puppet-enterprise

**The problem:**
Servers running puppet agent in my environment are receiving empty [classes] (without parameters), instead of the expected parameters stored in their Hiera document. This causes puppet modules to run with null parameters which in turn causes them to *successfully* run with **default** values instead of the actual expected values (which is obviously unwanted and destructive behavior).

**What causes the problem to trigger?**
Our Hiera are based on CouchDB document database (as I will further expand on later). When the CouchDB service is down the puppet agents (upon asking the puppet-masters for a new catalog) receive empty [classes] (without parameters), instead of the expected parameters stored in their Hiera document.

**My environment architecture:**

- 4 Puppet master servers under NetworkLoadBalancer (Cisco Ace)
- 1 puppet ca server
- 2 Hiera servers (couchDB 1.6.0)behind NetworkLoadBalancer (Cisco Ace)
- all the servers OS are RedHat 6.3
- Puppet version 3.7.4
- Puppet masters communicate with hiera servers with [Http_Backend](https://github.com/crayfishx/hiera-http) v1.0.1
- Using puppetDB with postgress sql to save servers inventory

**How are we able to simulate the problem?**

- By stopping the CouchDB service on the Hiera server - hiera01 (just one of the two) we are able to trigger the problem.
- puppet-masters logs show "connection refused ..." error for the sessions that were already open to the hiera01 server for more than 20 minutes
- sessions not being closed when the couchdb services is stopped.
- new requests are routed to hiera02.
- ***client servers that their session to get catalog from master through hiera01 - got default params for their classes !!!***

**Puppet master`s main configuration file**

```
[main]
logdir = /var/log/puppet
rundir = /var/run/puppet
ssldir = %vardir/ssl {group = service, mode = 640}
ca = false
certname = master_server_01.domain
dns_alt_names = puppet-master-ace.domain, puppet-master-ace
use_srv_records = true
pluginsource = puppet:///plugins
pluginfactsource = puppet:///pluginfacts
reports = log, foreman
enviromentpath = $confdir/enviroments
basemodulepath = $confdir/modules

[agent]
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

[master]
storeconfigs = true
storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
always_cache_features = true
```

**Hiera.yaml (master server)**

```
---
:backends:
 - http
 - yaml
:hierarchy:
 - "%{fqdn}"
 - "%{enviroment}"
 - common
:http:
 :host: hieraserverace.domain
 :use_auth: true
 :auth_user: admin
 :auth_pass: Passowrd
 :api_user: apiUser
 :api_pass: apipassword
 :merge_behavior: deeper
 :port: 5984
 :output: json
 :failure: graceful
 :path:
  - "/%{environment}/%{fqdn}"
  - "/%{environment}/%{osfamily}"
  - "/%{environment}/%{enviroment}"
  - "/%{environment}/common"

:yaml:
 :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
```

**Notes**

- environment is productions and updating versions is almost
  impossible.
- hieradata directory is empty (not using the yaml backend)

Thank you !

PS: Since we are running a classified environment disconnected from the internet uploading log files is a very complicated process.

Comment: Any reason you have `failure: graceful`? Apparently, this will make the hiera http backend ignore http errors: https://github.com/crayfishx/lookup_http/blob/master/lib/lookup_http.rb#L83 . Call [here](https://github.com/crayfishx/hiera-http/blob/master/lib/hiera/backend/http_backend.rb#L84)

Comment: There is no reason for `failure: graceful` parameter. After deleting this parameter, puppet agents raised an exeption `bad http response` and did not run successfuly even with both Hiera services (01 & 02) running. Adding another parameter ` :ignore_404: true` (without the failure parameter) fixed puppet agents exeptions.
But still when one of the Hiera services stops (Hiera01), The sessions are not being closed as expected ( the expected behavior is closing the session and trying again to Hiera02).